# How to set up Ububtu with desktop on VPS?

Tags: apt, server, desktop-environments

I've been developing an app with a server component and now need to move it to a virtual private sever so it can do its thing.  The hosting service I'm using only provides Ubuntu OS, and I'm trying to figure out how to install a desktop on it.  I'm not the strongest Linux user and I'd like to be able to connect remotely to configure things in a nice windowed environment.  The server itself also spawns a window when it runs, so I need to run it in an environment that supports windows.

I've tried following several online tutorials to get a desktop installed, but they all fail.  For example `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` ends in a long list of error messages that look like

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-are
s2_1.18.1-1ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
```

All my other attempts to `apt install` end in similar failures.  It's a fresh installation, so there shouldn't be anything there causing a conflict.  How would I go about setting up my VPS so I can somehow remote connect into a desktop?

Comment: try updating first, looks like it's trying to fetch the version for 22.04.1 and the site actually has 22.04.2 available. Do `apt update` and then `apt upgrade` and then try to install.